# Filtering line number when calling a text file from javascript into variable

Tags: javascript

I got this code, that will call all content of the File.txt into the variable fileContent. How can I make it get just ONE specified line number instead of the whole file content?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","data/File.txt",false);
xhr.send(null);
var fileContent = xhr.responseText;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the response text by line ending characters

```
// fileContent now  constain an array of strings
// where every item is a line
var fileContent = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
var lineNumber = 0;
var lineContent = fileContent[lineNumber]; // the content of the first line

// total number of lines
var linesCount = fileContent.length;

// random integer between 0 (minimum index) and linesCount - 1 (maximum index)
var randomLineNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * linesCount);
var randomLineContent = fileContent[randomLineNumber];
```

Comment: Is there a way to count how much lines are and take one random line?

Answer (score 0):

Split the file by newline and get the line number you want:

```
const lineNumber = 42;
const myLine = fileContent.split('\n')[lineNumber];
```

Or make it a bit more reusable:

```
const getLine = (content, lineNumber) => content.split('\n')[lineNumber];
getLine(fileContent, 42);
```

You do the error handling.